# DB2 and Stored Procedure - How to recover the bind parameters?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, bind, sql-pl

I'm writing a Stored Procedure (SQL / PL - DB2 V11 or later)
and I need to access the SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS to retrieve the columns of 'HELLO_WORLD' table.

On SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS the table 'HELLO_WORLD' is present with different TBCREATOR.

```
TBCREATOR |  TBNAME      | NAME
OWN_SV    |  HELLO_WORD  | COLN1
OWN_SV    |  HELLO_WORD  | COLN2
OWN_SV    |  HELLO_WORD  | COLN3
OWN_CL    |  HELLO_WORD  | COLN1
OWN_CL    |  HELLO_WORD  | COLN2
OWN_CL    |  HELLO_WORD  | COLNA
```

I won't to use the DISTINCT statement because the columns could be different.
I thought I would use the value in the special register CURRENT_SCHEMA but unfortunately not correct.

Example:

```
 SELECT C.NAME, C.COLNO
 FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS C
 WHERE C.TBCREATOR = CURRENT_SCHEMA
 AND C.TBNAME = 'HELLO_WORLD'
 ORDER OF C.COLNO
```

The value present in the CURRENT_SCHEMA it's incorrect: if the Stored Procedure
is called by another process (for example: A COBOL process) the CURRENT_SCHEMA is 
related to the process that verified the call.

The process that call my stored procedure "settings" CURRENT_SCHEMA with value "USERBTC"
(which is the user who executed the COBOL process via JCL)

My OWNER/TBCREATOR is "OWN_CL" and this value is specified in the bind parameters (more precisely, the parameter 'QUALIFIER')

To be sure of getting the table correctly I should use the QUALIFIER (OR OWNER) specified in the BIND options.

It's possible?
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you pass the schema-name as an input-parameter to the stored-procedure, and use that value to match on TBCREATOR column?

Comment: But, if possible, I'd like to avoid that.
1) The calling program may not know this information
2) This information changes for each customer and for each environment.

Comment: I think that a way to do this could be to use a DB2 GLOBAL VARIABLE... But i discarded this idea because i would a compatible  solution  with ORACLE-11 (and ORACLE  DB don't allow GLOBAL VARIABLES).

Comment: i think you should use syscat.columns that is granted to public

Comment: Also using the 'SYSCAT.TABLES' view I would have the problem of the 'OWNER/QUALIFIER'. Am I wrong?